# How to retrieve old text and subtract from total - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow up question on an existing question. I am able to get total sub-price tof products that i selected and add up to get the grand total. Now, when an item is deselected, i want to subtract the price of the item being deselected from the existing grand total?

How do i get that done please?

When i try to get the `oldtext`, it is always 0 .. why is this happening?

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel" id="panel">

<div>


<div >
<p>   class="mygoods" >Total: <span  ></span></p> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        function order(food)
        { 

            var ad = JSON.parse(food.dataset.food);    
              if(food.checked == true)  {
            $('.panel').append(
                '<div class="container" style=" font-size:14px; "> '+ 
    '<p class="total" ><span class="sub-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p>'+
'<input size="50" type="text" class="form-control quantity" id="qty" placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]"  required/>'+


             '</div>'   
              )


            }
            else{
                var total = $(".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().find(".total").text();
                $(".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();

            if (total) {
                $('.mygoods span').text(function(oldtext) {
                    console.log('this is my old text '+oldtext)
                    return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;

                });
            }                 
                }         
        }




        $('.panel').on('keyup','.quantity',function()

               {
                var sum;


                container = $(this).closest('div');

               quantity = Number($(this).val());
                price = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));    

               container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);

                sum = 0;



               $(".sub-total").each(function(){
               sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
               })                

               $('.mygoods span').text(sum);

               });

            </script>
```

Comment: Can I have HTML please?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER thats my html... my panel and a <p> which displays my grand total

Comment: for substraction you must convert text to integer or float using parseInt() or parseFloat() functions

Comment: how is that related to my issue please? @SamaBalaYam.  I am not looking for conversion. I am trying to get the `oldtext` that is my grand total ...i want to subtract the price of the item being deselected from the grand total

Comment: @pogba are not subtracting values?

Comment: @pogba You need to capture the value in the else part before the remove code.

Comment: In case of float values return use oldtext ? parseFloat(oldtext) -parseFloat( total) : oldtext;
In case of integer values use return oldtext ? parseInt(oldtext) -parseInt( total) : oldtext;

Comment: @priyadarshiswain that is what i want to get but i am not able to. can you help me?

Comment: @SamaBalaYam, please read my question and understand it well

Comment: I strongly recommend you try something like Angular or another template system. Your life could be more happier. But, in this case it seems more easier to do what you want to do handling those values using "onchange" event instead "keyup" event. I can´t see any reason to analyze those values on "typping-time". Off course, I can be wrong!

Comment: @pogba Please refactor your code and add sum more details like from where you are passing the oldtext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $( '.mygoods span' ).text( function( oldtext ) {
    console.log( 'this is my old text ' + oldtext )
    return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;
  } );
```

the `.text` method returns the parameters `index` and `text` - you only are retrieving one. Therefore the `index` is being stored in the `oldtext` variable, not the text.

> Type: Function( Integer index, String text ) => String A function
>   returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the
>   element in the set and the old text value as arguments.
>   http://api.jquery.com/text/

You can fix this by simply adding another parameter.

```
$( '.mygoods span' ).text( function(index, oldtext ) {
console.log( 'this is my old text ' + oldtext )
return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;
} );
```

I tried copying a snippet over to show you, but the code you provided is not enough to build anything. The attempted build is below.

```js
function order( food ) {
  var ad = JSON.parse( food.dataset.food );
  if ( food.checked == true ) {
    $( '.panel' ).append( '<div class="container" style=" font-size:14px; "> ' +
      '<p class="total" ><span class="sub-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p>' +
      '<input size="50" type="text" class="form-control quantity" id="qty" placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]"  required/>' +
      '</div>' )
  } else {
    var total = $( ".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]" ).parent().find(
      ".total" ).text();
    $( ".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]" ).parent().remove();
    if ( total ) {
      $( '.mygoods span' ).text( function( index,  oldtext ) {
        console.log( 'this is my old text ' + oldtext )
        return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;
      } );
    }
  }
}
$( '.panel' ).on( 'keyup', '.quantity', function() {
  var sum;
  container = $( this ).closest( 'div' );
  quantity = Number( $( this ).val() );
  price = Number( $( this ).closest( 'div' ).find( '.price' ).data( 'price' ) );
  container.find( ".total span" ).text( quantity * price );
  sum = 0;
  $( ".sub-total" ).each( function() {
    sum = sum + Number( $( this ).text() );
  } )
  $( '.mygoods span' ).text( sum );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="panel">
    <div>
      <div>
        <p class="mygoods"> Total: <span></span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So how then do i receive the figure itself please?